# How to insert key in object based on Id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of object, I want to add key in my specifi object of array when Id is matched. I have tried this:

```
this.data.forEach(value => {
              if (value.Id === attachmentDataId) {
                AttachmentTypeId: this.attachmentRecord.AttachmentType;
              }
            });
```

But it's not working and it's not giving any error also

Comment: Try changing the body of if block to ```value.AttachmentTypeId = this.attachmentRecord.AttachmentType;```

Comment: Can you give more details/context? Try creating a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is `this.data`? What is value of `attachmentDataId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `index` parameter of `forEach` function to access the specific object of the array.

```js
this.data.forEach((value, i) => {
  if (value.Id === attachmentDataId) {
    this.data[i] = { 
      ...this.data[i],
      AttachmentTypeId: this.attachmentRecord.AttachmentType
    };
  }
});
```

Inside the `if` block, you could also instead do

```js
this.data[i]['AttachmentTypeId'] = this.attachmentRecord.AttachmentType;
```

I just find using the spread operator cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
 let data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 5 }];

  const attachmentDataId = 5;

  const attachmentRecord = { AttachmentType: "AttachmentType" };

  data.forEach(value => {
    if (value.id === attachmentDataId) {
      value.AttachmentTypeId = attachmentRecord.AttachmentType;
    }
  });
```

The stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nrhouh

Answer (score 0):

use javascript map() method.
Map() return a new array, it takes a callback, iterates on each element in that array

```
const updatedData = data.map(res => {
   if(res.id === attachmentDataId) {
   res.AttachmentTypeId = attachmentRecord.AttachmentType;
    }
   return res
 })
```